# Create Add in Buttons in compose\read message window in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio, outlook, add-in

I have 2 VBA macro codes that run in Outlook 2007.

1. Search and replace text by clicking a button in Compose Mail Window
2. Search and replace text by clicking a button in Inbox Message Window

I need to create an application file to automatically install the buttons in the toolbar window for other users to run the macros.

As far as I know, I need to use Visual Studio to create an add in and then I need to program it accordingly to perform the operation.

Is there any other way to do the application file, or is using Visual Studio the only way?

If using Visual Studio is the only way, I have seen some sample add ins that create buttons in the main Outlook 2007 window, but have not seen any sample add in that create buttons in the **compose window toolbar/read message window toolbar**.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to create the add in for Outlook 2007.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found exactly what I need to do..I was about to add ribbon button in both Compose Window and Read message window toolbar. Please see this link. It was very helpful for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/12/15/making-a-custom-group-appear-in-the-message-tab-of-a-mail-item-norm-estabrook.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Hey, what project type would I need to select to be able to see the designer ? I am using Outlook 2013 add in for Visual studio as my project type, and there I cannot see any option fr designer.

Comment: There is nothing specific in the link that points anyone to what is was that addresses your problem.  This answer may as well have pointed to the microsoft.com website.